# Pandas group multiple columns and append value based on condition in non-grouped column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to group several columns in my dataframe, then append a new column to the original dataframe with a non-aggregated value determined by a condition in another column that falls outside of the grouping. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo','foo',
                         'bar', 'bar', 'bar',' bar','bar', 'bar'],
                   'subcat' : ['a', 'a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b',
                         'c', 'c','c','d', 'd', 'd'],
                   'bin' : [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                  'value':[2,5,7,6,3,9,8,3,2,1,2,4]
                  })
```

I'd like to group by both 'cat' and 'subcat', and I'm hoping to append the corresponding 'value' as a new column where 'bin' == 1.

This is my desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo','foo',
                         'bar', 'bar', 'bar',' bar','bar', 'bar'],
                   'subcat' : ['a', 'a','a', 'b', 'b', 'b',
                         'c', 'c','c','d', 'd', 'd'],
                   'bin' : [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
                  'value':[2,5,7,6,3,9,8,3,2,1,2,4],
                   'new_value':[2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,4]
                  })
```

I've tried various approaches including the following, but my merge yields more rows than expected so am hoping to find a different route.

```
vals = df[df['bin'] == 1].loc[:,('cat', 'subcat', 'value')]
df_merged = pd.merge(left = df, right = vals,  how = "left", on = ('cat','subcat'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `loc` with `groupby` and `idxmax`:

```
df['new_value'] = df.loc[df.groupby(['subcat'])['bin'].transform('idxmax'), 'value'].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     cat subcat  bin  value  new_value
0    foo      a    1      2          2
1    foo      a    0      5          2
2    foo      a    0      7          2
3    foo      b    0      6          3
4    foo      b    1      3          3
5    foo      b    0      9          3
6    bar      c    0      8          2
7    bar      c    0      3          2
8    bar      c    1      2          2
9    bar      d    0      1          4
10   bar      d    0      2          4
11   bar      d    1      4          4
```